# Bukkit plugin for servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a plugin in which where if you hover over a item it shows a little picture below it? I've seen it in The Archon using the teleporter compass thingy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to say, but Bukkit is **not** able to send / display images in the client (without using mods).

You are probably speaking of a modification.

---

Edit: A modification that you might have seen is *[Thaumcraft](http://i1113.photobucket.com/albums/k517/acemagex/2013-01-07_024614_zps400f78ec.png)* (there is a multiplayer version of the mod):
[image: Thauncraft item aspects]

To do this without using a specific mod you need an API for the client. A client has to install it manually, but then for example Bukkit plugins can send images and stuff to the client. An API that could do this would be *[Spoutcraft](http://spoutcraft.org/)* (for Bukkit), but I do not know any plugins that do what you want. You might need to write the plugin yourself or have someone doing this for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are APIs available which allow plugins to set the item meta to a picture, but I haven't seen any. It'd be best to ask around on the [bukkit forums](http://forums.bukkit.org) for something like this.